# How to render a text field in a radio radio button in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I need to translate the option that in a list, the current code does not run. The function `tr()` does the translation from one term to another in a .csv dictionary.

```
radioButtons(
              "enc",
              renderText({tr("Select encoding in case your data presents strange characters:")}),
              choices = c(
                renderText({tr("Automatic")}) = "unknown",
                "UTF-8" = "UTF-8",
                "Windows" = "Latin-1"
              ),
              selected = "unknown",
              inline = TRUE
            )
```

The current result:

```
Error in source("server/body.R", local = TRUE) : 
server/body.R:86:48: unexpected '='
                 choices = c(
                 renderText({tr("Browse")}) =
                                               ^
```

Comment: Tried  
     output$automaticchoice <- renderText({tr("Browse")}),     and then uiOutput("automaticchoice") = "unknown" ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reproducible example would be very helpful. For us to get started quick and for you to ensure the answer fits your request.

If you want to use dynamic ui elements, you should use `renderUI()`.

Also you should double check some basics,... `renderText()` produces and output and should not be used within another `render()` function.

I simulated the `tr()` function with: 
`tr <- function(name) return(paste("TR:", name))`.

A full working example is below, from there on you should be able to integrate it in your code. Good luck!:

```
library(shiny)

tr <- function(name) return(paste("TR:", name))

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("radio"),
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$radio <- renderUI({
    opt <- c("Normal" = "norm",
             "Uniform" = "unif",
             "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
             "Exponential" = "exp")
    names(opt)[1] <- tr("Normal")
    label <-  tr("Distribution type:")

    radioButtons("dist", label, opt)
  })  

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   norm = rnorm,
                   unif = runif,
                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                   exp = rexp,
                   rnorm)

    hist(dist(500))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```